# Array values replace with another array values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new in php:

how to replace array A values with array B values in php. 
If array A size is larger than array B.

Ex: Array A size is 10 -> ie. {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'}
    Array B size is 5 -> ie. {'1','2','3','4','5'}

then, how to replace array B values from 5th position of the array A values

Pls anybody clear my doubt with php coding.

Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: I am sure that we can help but the question is not clear, can you clarify it by giving the desired result please?

Comment: give us an example of your desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to determine what you are trying to achieve from your post, but i would take a look at [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).